# ConnectFour Win condition

Tags: algorithm, jframe

I have a ConnectFour program that uses a really big if statement to check if there is a winner, but it only seems to work with the tiles (JButtons) in the middle work with my code. The edges, not so much... If you can see what I did wrong so that this if state would work, that would be great!

Source Code:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Color;    
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ConnectFour extends JPanel
{
    private int turn;
    private final JButton BOARD[][];
    private final Color DEFAULT_COLOR;

    public ConnectFour()
    {
        super(new GridLayout(6, 7));
        turn = 0;

        BOARD = new JButton[6][7];
        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        for(int i = 0; i < BOARD.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < BOARD[i].length; j++)
            {
                BOARD[i][j] = new JButton("");
                BOARD[i][j].addActionListener(handler);
                if(!(i == BOARD.length - 1))
                {
                    BOARD[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                }
                add(BOARD[i][j]);
            }
        }
        DEFAULT_COLOR = BOARD[0][0].getBackground();
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame("test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(new ConnectFour());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        JButton source = ((JButton) event.getSource());
        if(turn % 2 == 0)
        {
            source.setBackground(Color.RED);
            source.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            source.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            source.setEnabled(false);
        }

        boolean winner = checkWinner();

        if(winner)
        {
            System.out.println("Player " + (turn % 2 + 1) + " wins!");
        }
        //---------------------------------
        for(int i = 0; i < BOARD.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < BOARD[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(BOARD[i][j].equals(source))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        BOARD[i - 1][j].setEnabled(true);
                        break;
                    }
                    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                    {
                        //System.out.println("Hello, World!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        turn++;
    }

    private boolean checkWinner()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < BOARD.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < BOARD[i].length; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(((BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 1][j].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 2][j].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 3][j].getBackground()))
                     && !(BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(DEFAULT_COLOR)))
                    || ((BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i - 1][j].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i - 2][j].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i - 3][j].getBackground()))
                     && !(BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(DEFAULT_COLOR)))
                    || ((BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i][j + 1].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i][j + 2].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i][j + 3].getBackground()))
                     && !(BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(DEFAULT_COLOR)))
                    || ((BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i][j - 1].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i][j - 2].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i][j - 3].getBackground()))
                     && !(BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(DEFAULT_COLOR)))
                    || ((BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 1][j + 1].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 2][j + 2].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 3][j + 3].getBackground()))
                     && !(BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(DEFAULT_COLOR)))
                    || ((BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 1][j - 1].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 2][j - 2].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 3][j - 3].getBackground()))
                     && !(BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(DEFAULT_COLOR)))
                    || ((BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i - 1][j + 1].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i - 2][j + 2].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i - 3][j + 3].getBackground()))
                     && !(BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(DEFAULT_COLOR)))
                    || ((BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i - 1][j - 1].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i - 2][j - 2].getBackground()))
                     && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i - 3][j - 3].getBackground()))
                     && !(BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(DEFAULT_COLOR))))
                        return true;
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Here's a Connect4 javascript toy I made several years ago and then uploaded several years after that. If you view source on the HTML all of the code should be in there https://googledrive.com/host/0B23IV_kQJJ8wb2piRTE5ZXhCV3M/  if you know the position of the last peice you can check all of the possible runs around it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason as to why you have this bug is because you code is difficult to read in the first place. You *should* be able to solve this without our help. Messy code means bugs will creep up on you.

Some comments:

1) add java to the languages that this post pertains to

2) instead of "i" and "j" consider using "height" and "width" (or "h" and "w") such that as a reader of your code I can tell which axis these variables refer to.

3) separate each (if) case into it's own methods. You appear to know how to use methods so take advantage of them! Make your code readable and you will solve this quickly.

For example:

```
            if(((BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 1][j].getBackground()))
             && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 2][j].getBackground()))
             && (BOARD[i][j].getBackground().equals(BOARD[i + 3][j].getBackground()))
```

I believe is checking for a "vertical" or "horizontal" line of similar colors (I cannot tell because I do not know what i and j are). So why not wrap that in a method called "checkVertical" that returns true of false.

4) Learn how to use debuggers. They are VERY easy to use and you will probably solve your problem right away doing so.